# How to convert an external image to a local image for canvases?

Tags: image, canvas, download, external

How can I convert external images to local images?
I found this page `http://www.maxnov.com/getimagedata/#download` but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Yes, that maxnov.com hack is no longer working in the current versions of browsers.  Why not just load the necessary images on your server and let the user download from your domain?

Comment: Theres a lot of images, and I would rather just try to figure out a way to get the data uri of external images.

Comment: I don't think there is a hack that browsers won't quickly disallow for valid security reasons.  If you don't want to host "a lot of images" on your server, you can just bounce the external images off your server.  For example, check out PHPs file_get_contents or something similar depending on your servers O/S.